# Hadoop application log size

Tags: hadoop

I was going through data node log and for one particular application id I see below steps

At very first step it showing application id with number of bytes

```
application_0970580980111_1399512/  4096 bytes  Aug 24, 2016 10:27:10 PM
```

inside this folder I can see many containers . like

```
container_095860509_1399512_01_000001/  4096 bytes  Aug 24, 2016 10:09:46 PM 
container_09586050091_1399512_01_000428/  4096 bytes  Aug 24, 2016 10:13:40 PM
```

And lastly inside one container , we have all required logs

```
stderr  2043 bytes  Aug 24, 2016 10:24:18 PM 
stdout  0 bytes  Aug 24, 2016 10:09:45 PM 
syslog  297178648 bytes  Aug 24, 2016 10:29:02 PM
```

I can see syslog is about 297178648 bytes , So what is significant of showing 4096 bytes for container and application level.

Comment: which ecosystem component are you using, you might need to adjust your logging to minimize log message, Change log level to error or some thing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4096 bytes is "kinda default" size for a folder. Unix doesn't calculate total file size for a folder even if there are actually files inside some folder. In your case `container` folder is there hence default 4096 bytes, exclusive of size of `stderr` or `stdout` or `syslog`. 
Another relevant fact is if you try `hadoop fs -ls /someFolder`, you will get 0 as size. Probably worse than 4096 even.